# Eclipse luna - Internal error, trying to import from git

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am using Eclipse Luna, and I am trying to import a project from github. However, it says "Internal error; consult Eclipse error log" when I pasted the URI in:

[image]

The project is valid. I've tried a few projects, and they all worked on my older Juno version of eclipse, but all failed on Luna, just like above. What should I do to reproduce this problem?

Here is my Eclipse log error: http://pastebin.com/QcfF4Xsq

Comment: It looks like you need to have Git installed.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I do have it installed. I have Git installed on my computer, and EGit plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a similar error message with [other Eclipse-based products, like RTC](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/106905/unable-to-locate-secure-storage-module-orgeclipseequinoxsecuritywindowspasswordprovider-self-answer):

> A summary of the problem is that Eclipse uses a default location on your machine that is the same for all your Eclipse installs.
>   So if you have installed and used 32-bit Eclipse, then your secure storage requires the 32-bit plugins to access.
>   When you try to use a 64-bit Eclipse, it will try to read that secure storage and will fail because it is using the 64-bit plugins to read the storage.
>
> The solution is to tell your Eclipse to use a different secure storage area. You can do this by running Eclipse with the following option:

```
-eclipse.keyring <file_path>
```

> where `<file_path>` is the location of the file which you wish to use as your new secure storage area.

(You can check by the way if you have a consistent Eclipse distribution: all 32 bits or all 64 bits)

Note that another product (NetBeans) resolved the same error message like so ([issue 211863](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211863))

> I found the problem.
>   NetBeans is detecting a remnant of an Eclipse IDE installation.  Once I deleted the file, the errors in the log went away.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ttroy\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage
```

On Windows 7 or more:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage 
# or
%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I run eclipse with options (like you mentioned)

Comment: You can add this option in the eclipse.ini file which is in the same folder as the eclipse.exe.

Comment: In Windows 8 the folder is at: C:\Users\USERNAME\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage . If you delete it and restart Eclipse the import will work.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for this answer, I know this is against the SO policy to comment like this but I will this time :)

Answer (score 18):

I solved this problem going to "Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage > Contents", open "[Default Secure Storage]", deleting the "GIT" row and finally restarting Eclipse.

Comment: The best suggestion that worked in the simplest way possible... You know what you talk and suggest @russellhoff

Comment: Same here - I had the error "no password provided" as soon as I entered the git URL. This solution worked

Comment: This is what easy and acceptable answer of this question. thanks @russelhoff

Comment: the solution provided by @russelhoff worked for me like a magic!!

Answer (score 15):

Delete `C:\Users\USERNAME\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage` it will resolve your problem.

Comment: This looks perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the message I see in the eclipse Error log.

*Secure storage was unable to retrieve the master password from the OS keyring. Make sure that this application has access to the OS keyring. If the error persists, the password recovery feature could be used, or secure storage can be deleted and re-created.*

So as others said if you delete the secure_storage file and it should solve the problem.
On a mac, better use command line.

```
/Users/< userid >/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security
```

Comment: If you are using mac, use command prompt to access the file under /Users/<userid>/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security/